# System of distinct representatives / Transversal

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

> Determine for which $k,n\in \mathbb N, 1\le k \le n$ the collection of finite sets $\{1,2,...,n\}\choose k$ has a system of distinct representatives / transversal.

Well I think the solution is $k=n,k=1,k=n-1$. But I don't know how to prove it. I should verify the Hall condition (Hall marriage theorem) somehow, but how? To be more precise, how to verify that the Hall condition is met **only for these** $k,n$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If there are more than $n$ sets in the collection, then you can't have a transversal, can you?

Comment: I think so, so that's a sufficient argument? That means I'm looking for all subsets of $k$ elements such that their cardinality is lower than $n$. That means ${n \choose k} \le n$. By solving this equation I get solution for only $k=n$, $k=1$ and $k=n-1$. Am I right?

Comment: Looks that way to me.